# How to split .zip files and join them in Windows?

Tags: windows, zip, unzip

I need to split a .zip file in Ubuntu as .z01, .z02 etc... so that I would join them back in Windows.

I don't have access to command prompt in Windows. How would I unzip files now?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On Ubuntu you can use the `split` command to split your zip file. Something like this should work:

```
split your-zip.zip -b 32M ZIPCHUNKS
```

This will create a bunch of ZIPCHUNKS* files, in order, and all 32 MB or less in size. Change the 32M parameter to vary the chunk size.

Traditionally you'd use `cat` to glue them back together:

```
cat ZIPCHUNKS* > reassembled-zip.zip
```

Since you want to do the reassembling on Windows, you need a substitute for `cat`. [Is there replacement for cat on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows) may help, but note that the Windows `type` command will not work as it adds the files names between them when processing more than one file. One working approach is `copy /b ZIPCHUNKS* > reassembled-zip.zip`.

You can also use `rar` which natively supports creating "split" archives which can then be decompressed by a GUI tool on Windows such as WinZip or WinRar. On Ubuntu, install the `rar` package, then:

```
rar a -v32M destination.rar files/to/compress
```

This will create files called destination.partXX.rar. Transfer these to Windows, then unrar the first one (destination.rar), which will link to the others automatically.

One trick you can potentially use is to "rar" the original zip file, that way you can reassemble it on Windows. If you have the original files, it may be easier to just rar them and work with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help on split command as well as the stackoverflow link. Really helpful. I'm wondering now that I don't even have access to command line. How do I unzip the splitted files now?

Comment: Your command ZIPCHUNKS creates ZIPCHUNKSaa, etc.. They are of unknown file type. I wonder whether they'll be detected in windows

Comment: The "chunks" are not stand-alone zip files, they need to be put back together in order for the zip file to be valid. I'll update my answer to show a way of doing this with `rar`, which can produce "chunked" archives (called "volumes) *and* be decompressed with WinZip (which I hope you have installed) or WinRAR. If not, you'd have to tell me which archive management tools are installed on your Windows system.

Comment: yes, the chunks themselves are unrecognizable, I wouldn't trust Windows to detect them as anything, that's why I mentioned you have to reassemble them somehow, then rename the resulting file to .zip. But the pieces themselves will be useless until reassembled.

Comment: Thanks roadmr. I used zip command with --out option and they're recognizable in windows

Answer (score 17):

Use `zip` command with `-s split_size` to compress files.
The example command is following.

```
zip -r -s 100m filename.zip  compress_folder
```

Answer (score 4):

Very easy: you first do `split your-zip.zip -b 32M ZIPCHUNKS` in Linux/Unix and then `type * > myZipFile.zip` in Windows.

Comment: Your answer seems to be a copy of @roadmr accepted answer

Comment: @Yaron No it's not. It's a very straight-forward version of his answer. His answer did not contain the part relevant to gluing the split zip files back in Windows.

Comment: type will add the file names and formatting when given multiple files. use copy /b *.in file.out instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this a year or more ago. It is inconvenient, because Windows just doesn't have the same tools.

I ended up using [GSplit](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/), which does work under WINE (or PlayOnLinux). It creates a `.exe` file and a bunch of `.gsd` files. If you are zipping a PDF file, you need to pre-zip it because Windows gets confused!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have permissions to install any tools where I need to join the files

Comment: In that case, you'll have to use the solution that roadmr gave, using `copy /b` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have zip installed on your Ubuntu machine, you should also have [zipsplit](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipsplit.html). This takes a large zip file and splits it into a number of smaller, stand-alone zip files. It doesn't rely on any particular version of WinZip or Rar to work, as the files it makes are plain Zip files.

One caveat: zipsplit still lives in the world of CP/M / MS-DOS 8.3 file names, so if you use it on *biglongfilename.zip*, you'll end up with *biglon_1.zip*, *biglon_2.zip*, *biglon_3.zip*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 7Zip. It is available for Ubuntu and Windows ([download link here](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)). A GUI is available for either operating system, but you can just as easily use a CLI. There is a textbox (in the GUI) where you put the size of each split zip file. You can use K (kilobyte), M (megabyte), or G (gigabyte) for sizes that are not included in the dropdown menus.

7Zip split volumes:

[image: 7Zip Split Volumes]

Through the CLI, you can use the `-v` switch to determine the volume size.

In order to reassemble the files, decompress the first file (i.e. `*.zip.001`). [1](https://7-zip.opensource.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/volume.htm)