# 6 gig file won't fit on 8 gig flash drive

Tags: files

I have a 6.4 GB file.  I have a 8 GB flash drive.

Why won't the file fit on the flash drive?  More importantly, how do I get the file onto the drive?

Comment: Is the flash drive FAT32 formatted? FAT32 has a 4GB file size limit.

Comment: this might help, http://askubuntu.com/questions/228315/split-zip-file-and-join-them-in-windows

Comment: -ETOOVAGUE: This is a really good example of a really bad question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ethanbmnz said, you likely have a FAT formatted drive.

So your options are To split the file, however it will need to be "glued" back together to be usable

In my opinion, better option is reformat the drive in NTFS, this way it can be usable on both Windows and Linux and you don't have the 4GB file limit

Comment: Yep, I'd forgotten that fact about FAT formatting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if there are hidden directories and files that actually occupies space.

Type this in terminal/command line:

`ls -la`

If there are no other hidden directories or files, you may have formatted your thumb drive in FAT32.

You can also check the capacity of your thumb drive being reported by the OS.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Good things to check.  NOTE: this site is devoted to ubuntu, so don't include windows instructions.